# $B^{0}$ decay into $K^{+}$ and $K^{-}$: equally probable?

Tags: particle-physics, mesons

One of the decay modes of the $B^0$ meson is $B^0 \rightarrow K^{*0} \mu^{+}\mu^{-}$,

with $K^{*0} \rightarrow K^+ \pi^-$.

But because of the [$B$-meson oscillatios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E2%80%93Bbar_oscillation), we can also have $ B^0 \rightarrow \overline{B^0} \rightarrow \overline{K^{*0}} \mu^{+}\mu^{-}$,

with $\overline{K^{*0}} \rightarrow K^- \pi^+$

Is it equally probable to see $K^+$ and $K^-$ mesons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kind of questions I think the pdg booklet is your best friend. You can find the data for $B^0$ online here:
http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v0/pdgLive/Particle.action?node=S042
and follow the link for $K$ or $K^∗$ modes. In a first look, I couldn't find any decays including muons, which means that the first process is more probable. See the link for the exact numbers.